# Can a congregant who has been asked to open the Ark, walk in front of the Ark to get to the other side of the 'bimah'?

Tags: halacha, synagogue, torah-service, ark-aron-kodesh, opening-the-ark

Can a congregant who opened the Aron Hakodesh walk in front of the open ark and walk to the other side of the platform where the Aron is situated?

Comment: yehoshua, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for the interesting question! Please consider registering your account, to give you access to more of the site's features and help the site keep track of your contributions.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please clarify what the situation is? Has the congregant already opened it? Why is the congregant crossing over, and why do you think it might be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

My sense is it's just a matter of respect for the visibility of the open Aron; if all the congregants are looking at the Torah scrolls, you don't want to appear like you're hogging the attention and blocking their view.

If for whatever reason you need to be on the other side, I'd say just cross over as quickly and as unobtrusively as possible.

That's just my gut sense on the matter.